# Get List of Dicionary Value Property in c# using List of Keys

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary of Guid, Asset and I'd like to get the names from a list of keys that I have:

```
Dictionary<Guid, Asset> assetDict;

List<Guid> selectedAssetGuidList;  //subset of assetDict.Keys
```

From these Guid's I'd like to get all the Asset.name properties, namely a list of

```
assetDict[selectedAssetGuid].name
```

where selectedAssetGuid is one element in selectedAssetGuidList. Thanks Y'all

Comment: You mean `var enumerableWithNames = selectedAssetGuidList.Select(guid => assetDict[guid].name);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method syntax:

```
var result = selectedAssetGuidList.Select(guid => assetDict[guid].name);
```

or query syntax:

```
var result = from guid in selectedAssetGuidList
             select assetDict[guid].name;
```